# Extjs look and feel

Tags: extjs

I have very simple grid which contains a lot of data - so my scroll ball is quite narrow. I edit data in cells. Left to my grid there is picture with coordinates points. I wish this behavior: when I click on coordinate point I want to go to corresponding grid row. They are related by id(id row = id point div). How can it be made? 
Also when I edit grid in the middle and bind coordinates of new point to row(by using store) - the grid gets automatically reloaded after store is updated - and scroll gets to the top. How can I track last edited row in the middle of the list so I can auotmatically focus on it? Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use the `focusRow` method (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.view.Table-method-focusRow) to scroll where you want, for example :

```
yourGrid.getView().focusRow(10);
```

To disable the 'scroll to the top" effect when you reload the grid, set `preserveScrollOnRefresh` to true on the viewConfig of your grid (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.view.Table-cfg-preserveScrollOnRefresh).